# How to choose value only in rows with last user interaction?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a table with a similar structure to this:

```
+----------------+---------+------------------+----------+
| interaction_id | user_id | interaction_time |  source  |
+----------------+---------+------------------+----------+
|              1 |       1 | TIMESTAMP A      | google   |
|              2 |       2 | TIMESTAMP B      | facebook |
|              3 |       1 | TIMESTAMP C      | facebook |
|              4 |       2 | TIMESTAMP D      | google   |
+----------------+---------+------------------+----------+
```

I am trying to do a last interaction attribution model and want to add a new column with the source value only if it is the last interaction per user. Let's say timestamp C is later than A and D is later than B
So the desired result looks like this:

```
+----------------+---------+-------------+----------+-------------+
| interaction_id | user_id |    time     |  source  | last_source |
+----------------+---------+-------------+----------+-------------+
|              1 |       1 | TIMESTAMP A | google   | NULL        |
|              2 |       2 | TIMESTAMP B | facebook | NULL        |
|              3 |       1 | TIMESTAMP C | facebook | facebook    |
|              4 |       2 | TIMESTAMP D | google   | google      |
+----------------+---------+-------------+----------+-------------+
```

I have tried joining a subselect with a MAX clause and using rank but have not gotten it to work. It either gives a value for all rows of the last_source column or for not of them.
Later we will be trying to do the opposite with a first interaction model, but I assume any solution could easily be tweaked to accomplish this.

Comment: Would it also be possible to have the output not contain the rows with last_source NULL? I could do it with a STRING_AGG afterwards but I have experienced that this hurts performance drastically.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you can go by `interaction_id` to define the "last" (as in the sample data), use conditional logic with `row_number()`:

```
select t.*,
       (case when row_number() over (partition by user_id order by interaction_id) = 1
             then source
        end) as last_source
from t;
```

Comment: Thanks. I should be able to do the same for timestamp correct?